# Дана несимметричная матрица, пересобрать только ее симметричные элементы python

Tags: python, матрицы

Пример: `[[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`
Должно на выходе выдавать: `[[0, 1], [1, 0]]`

Comment: а `[[0, 0], [0, 0]]` не считается ответом?

Comment: @strawdog  считается, если эти 2 нуля симметричны относительно главной диагонали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, я не совсем верно истолковал вопрос, но вот у меня есть такое решение:

Исходные:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
```

Сам код:

```
blocks = [a[x:x+2,x:x+2] for x in np.diag_indices(a.shape[0])[0][:-1]]
res = [x.tolist() for x in blocks if np.allclose(x, x.T)]
print(res)
```

Результат:

```
[[[0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Comment: оно не должно выдавать [[0, 0], [0, 0]] т.к те нули несимметричны относительно главной диагонали матрицы

Comment: Оказывается, симметричны.